# Is it possible to change rotation order of existing animation?

Tags: animation, armature, bones

there is animated armature but some bones euler rotation order needs to be changed due to gimbal lock. Is it possible to change rotation order of existing animation without changing original animation? I've tried it but animation looks strange. it does not look like original animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in 3D, gimbal lock isn't really some kind of lock, that happens at one specific orientation, like it is in engineering, which is where the term comes from.  It's really just wonky Euler interpolation that exists at all orientations, but is most apparent at certain orientations.  It's not some special thing that happens sometimes; it is always happening, and it's the way that Eulers interpolate.

So you can't really change the rotation order just for cases of gimbal lock, without affecting interpolation on other frames.  You can bake rotation to a bone with a different rotation mode, and then delete redundant keyframes, but that will change your interpolation for all frames, not just the ones that you've identified as gimbal locked.

What we *can* do is tell a bone to use a different rotation order for the span of a few keyframes via copy rotation constraints and visual transforms.

[image]

We're going to start with an XYZ Euler bone with interpolation we don't like across two keyframes.  (Here, we're rotating from 0,0,0 to 180,90,180.)  We'll add an empty, set its rotation mode to whatever we want (quaternion is usually best here, nobody actually wants Euler *interpolation*, they want the per-axis control), and then give it a copy rotation constraint, world->world, targeting the bone we want.

Then we'll go to the locations of each of our bone's keyframes, select the empty, apply visual transform, and keyframe rotation.  Then we'll delete the constraint.

Now we can constraint the bone from our empty.  We'll give it a copy rotation constraint targeting the empty, world->world.  At our current rotation keyframes, we'll keyframe that constraint to 1.0; at one frame earlier than the first keyframe, and one frame later than the last keyframe, we'll key it to 0.0.

[image]

Now, our XYZ Euler is using quaternion interpolation (from the empty's keyframes) for this span of our animation.

If we'd like, we could go on to bake this span of the animation with visual keying and clear constraints, so that we are no longer dependent on the empty.  This will create a keyframe every frame so that we are no longer relying on Euler interpolation:

[image]

Comment: your information is useful but what I want to do is not changing rotation order for a few keyframes, but I want it to be changed completely. RIght now I animated characters shoulder bone using wrong rotation order XZY, but it causes gimbal lock because I need to rotate Z axis by over 90 degrees so I want to change XZY to ZYX. Is it possible? I simply changed rotation order but it doesn't work.

Comment: How many keyframes?  You can do the same thing as I described, but over all keyframes, if you want.  If there are a lot of keyframes, that can be unwieldy, and scripting (or an addon if you can find one) would make it easier.  But, be aware, it will change your interpolations between keyframes; that's the whole point, after all.

Comment: it is 50 frames animation but it only has 3 keyframes. frame 1, frame 25 and frame 50 but its has bezier interpolation and I  need to change shoulder, forearm, and hand too. If it's not easy I will remake all manually. it will be impossible to make same bezier curve though.

Comment: Create an empty with appropriate mode, copy rotation to it local->world, bake keyframes on empty, delete all keyframes except 1, 25 and 50, change rotation on your bone, copy paste keyframes from your empty.  Yes, you're right, the custom f-curve handles are going to be lost; they're just not things that make sense in terms of a different rotation mode/Euler order.

Comment: ok. I will copy and paste animation using copy rotation constraint + empty.thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since Blender v3.1, there is a new addon named "Copy Global Transform".

> The Copy Global Transform add-on makes it possible to copy the world-space transform of the active object/bone, and paste it onto any object/bone.
>
> **Source: [Reference/Release Notes/3.1/Add-ons - Blender Developer Wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.1/Add-ons)**

What this allows you to do, if for any given keyframe, or selection of keyframes, you can copy the global transform, changed the rotation order, then paste the global transforms again.

Be aware though, that because of the rotation order difference, the interpolation that used to happen between frames before the rotation order change might change, sometimes drastically. So if you want to preserve the interpolation, use the "Paste and Bake" pasting, so that it will make new keyframes on every frame with whatever animation you had when copying.